# I have an error with image or gradle, don't know which one?

Tags: java, android, gradle

So we're working on an app for our uni as a project and we're totally new to Java, Android Studio and app design. We work together with git and the app runs with my teammates, but I can't get it to run anymore. I get this error:

```
Executing tasks: [:app:assembleDebug] in project \Project
```

> ```
> Task :app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:checkDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mainApkListPersistenceDebug UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:createDebugCompatibleScreenManifests UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:mergeDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:compileDebugShaders UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
> Task :app:processDebugJavaRes NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugAidl NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:compileDebugRenderscript NO-SOURCE
> Task :app:javaPreCompileDebug UP-TO-DATE
> ```
>
> Task :app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
>
> Task :app:mergeDebugResources FAILED
>      AGPBI: {"kind":"error","text":"The file name must end with .xml","sources":    [{"file":"\Project\app\src\main\res\merker\marker.png"}],"tool":"Resource and asset merger"}

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
```

\Project\app\src\main\res\merker\marker.png: Error: The file name must end with .xml

```
* Try:
```

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 6.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD FAILED in 1s
9 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 8 up-to-date

I deleted some of the file directory for privacy reasons.
I'm a total newbie with this, if anyone could help it would be really appreciated.

EDIT: The marker.png file is added to the drawable folder:
[marker.png inside the drawable folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VZjn3.jpg)

[file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5e9wi.jpg)

This is the piece of code where we use the marker. I already tried using a file ic_marker.xml and it recognizes it as a marker because the marker is shown in next to the line of code in the editor. But I still get the same error.

> ```
> public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
>     int height = 100;
>     int width = 100;
>     BitmapDrawable bitmapdraw=(BitmapDrawable)getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);
>     Bitmap b=bitmapdraw.getBitmap();
>     Bitmap smallMarker = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(b, width, height, false);
>     mMap = googleMap;
>     mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
>     mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
> ```

Comment: png images should be placed inside `res/drawable`.

Comment: Add the .png file inside the drawable folder

Comment: you are adding an image to your own created directory in res, better move that image to drawable directory.

Comment: Edited: about the png is located in the drawable folder

Comment: remove merker from your res directory

Answer (score 1):

Check your res folder.
its having another folder named "merker"  and this merker having image "merker.png"

in this folder you should add only XML files ..but you have added or by mistake you have added .png image file..

you have to remove this image file or its mistake then rename your file to .xml extension